# error: Cannot be resolved to a variable in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary, tagging

I am trying to teach myself how to programme in android, I am now trying to save user defined location from google map in android to SQLite, I am following a tutorial on youtube which was going perfectly fine until I got to this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UiShIimLsc&list=UULPTrmvMOpPYlgq4FDvN1iQ       video time: 1:10

When I got to this stage, I followed the instructions and added this line;

data = new MarkerDataSource(context); however my context is underlined red, giving me an error 'Cannot be resolved to a variable'.

I tried getting in contact with the person but no luck, could someone please guide me.

What I want to achieve at the end is save user's tagged location in SQlite and when the user closes and reopens the application the tagged location to appear.

Thanks.

Comment: Either try using `this` to replace `context`, or if that doesn't work you will need to post the class.

Comment: (this) isn't working either.

Comment: [name of class].this or better still post your side of the code..

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling it within an Activity or Service class, you should be able to use `this`. If you are calling it from within a fragment, try `getActivity()`.

Comment: It force closes upon launch.